# SQL select count distinct

Tags: sql

I want to know how many items of distinct name I have in my database.
When I use:

```
select count(distinct name) from products
```

I obviously gain only number of different, distinct names I have in my
database. I was experimenting with group by, but as a total beginner I
failed. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. Are you trying to find the number of rows that have a unique name that doesn't appear elsewhere in the table?

Comment: I don't understand you requirement, sorry. You do or don't want a count of distinct names in your table?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think @User is trying to get something along the lines of `product1 / 23`, `product2 / 67`, `product3 / 12`, etc.  Please confirm if this is correct?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Group by `name` and use `count()` to get the counts for each group

```
select name, count(*) 
from products
group by name
```

Comment: what if I want to obtain number of items for one specific name? I was experimenting with 'select name, count(*) from products group by name where name like "Book''' but it doesn't work

Comment: Well then you don't need to group at all: `select count(*) from products where name = 'Book'`. And BTW `where` comes before `group by` that is why your query did not work

Comment: Oh thank you, I was overthinking this one! One more thing, I'd like to pass argument to my SQL query, I don't know if it's possible? I've been trying with 'select count(*) from products where name = "&name"''

Comment: Sure, but that depends on the framework you use to execute your queries. Look into *Prepared Statements*

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(name) as ct, name from products group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) FROM products GROUP BY name
```